# postback problem when working with ajax updatepanel and jquery together

Tags: jquery, updatepanel, postback

I am working on asp.net and jquery. I used updatepanel and jquery together. Enerything is fine. But sometimes face postback problem. Suppose after running a page i test some jquery call which call pagemethod of the same page. After some event the submitt button is not working. I press several times but it do nothing. I am unable to find the problem.

Please help.

Comment: why would you ever use an update panel? :)  in all seriousness, i don't think this is enough info for someone to give you an entirely accurate answer.  can you post code?

Comment: i used updatepanel to update some portion of the page. Like load the gridview in the page. The problem is i have a submitt button that is used to save the data. I have some webmethod on that page. When a partial postback occurs, after that no postback element is working even the submitt button. Thats the problem.

Comment: its not clear what you are trying to accomplish with updatepanel & jquery. is the submit button inside the updatepanel? do you intend this button to postback or do a partial postback?

Comment: i used updatepanel to update some portion of the page. Like load the gridview in the page. Everything inside the updatepanel. The problem is i have a submitt button that is used to save the data. I have some webmethod on that page. When a partial postback occurs, after that no postback element is working even the submitt button. Thats the problem.

Comment: didn't anyone get me????????????

Answer (score 1):

When you hook up your events in jquery they are tied to dom elements that are replaced by the update panel.  Hence the events you hooked up are lost as their dom element is destroyed by the update panel's replacement elements.

You can use $("MySelector").live('click',function(){ alert('hi')});

It works by attaching an event handler for mouse click at the root dom node of your page that runs when the original source meets the selector criteria.  Events will bubble up the dom until they are handled and canceled.  This is a really handy tool for dealing with any code where you are dynamically replacing or adding buttons.  It is particularly helpful when you are unfortunate enough to have to deal with update panels.

You can also look into .delegate.  That would let you define the function at a parent node in the dom that is closer (thus having the event bubble up less and giving you more efficiency).  I have always been fine with just using .live

Answer (score 0):

If the jQuery that is tied to the button click is wrapped in a $(document).ready it will loose the jQuery action that was tied to it on an update panel postback. Microsoft asp.net Ajax automatically calls a function called pageLoad, so do the following.

Set it up like this :

pageLoad(){
       $('#button1').click(function(){
           //do something
       });
}

Not this :

$(document).ready(function(){
       $('#button1').click(function(){
           //do something
       });
});

Comment: submitt button under updatepanel. And i am using updatepanel when submitting the form for data save. But it not working after some partial update by jquery.

Comment: i am badly in problem? Looking for someone.